# Multiple node.js apps on the same server

Tags: nginx, node.js

I have nginx hosts an instance of static site generated by jekyll.

I added a nodejs app on port 4000 and do according to [this tutorial on DigitalOcean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-host-multiple-node-js-applications-on-a-single-vps-with-nginx-forever-and-crontab)

```
server {
  listen    80;

  root /usr/share/nginx/html/example.com;
  index index.html index.htm;

  server_name example.com;
  charset utf-8;

  location /nodeapp/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:4000/;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
  }
}
```

The app loads but all the static resources get 404 because it looks for resource at `example.com/nodeapp/css/main.css` for example.

How would i fix this?

Comment: Please include complete configuration for `nginx` in the question.

Comment: The word "multiple" is throwing me off, care to clarify?

Comment: @c4urself i want to run more nodejs apps when diff port and map it to like `example.com/app1/` and `example.com/app2/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the following before any proxy logic and store assets in a directory elsewhere on the machine:

```
location /static {
    alias /location/for/all/static/assets;
}
```

Then, in your app make "/static" the prefix for all static assets.

Comment: So I will have to define a path dedicated for each app like `/static1/` for app1 and so on ? or create a single alias path and copy all the asset to it ?

Comment: You could do `/static/app1` `/static/app2` for example.

Comment: Thank you. It seems reasonable to me. I will try it later. Thank you.